# Card view constant height to mimic view pager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Fellow programmers, is there a method to set a constant height in Card View? I would like to mimic android view pager.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow, did you try setting the CardView a numbered height?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting CardView to a numbered height, reason being I would like it to match _parent on multiple devices. From what I understand CardViews have a constant width but a variable height. And height is determined by the collection of objects displayed in the card.I would like to set height to match_ parent in order to have it scroll one card at a time through the uses view, and not be dependent on the objects it contains.

Comment: I failed to mention I am working with cards in RecyclerView.

Comment: After replacing CardView with a FrameLayout in RecyclerView, I realized it was not CardView causing the problem. It appears that it is not possible to set a Layout to match_parent height “devise screen height” within RecyclerView. Ultimately what I need for my project is an endless vertical ViewPager that I can supply fragments to during run time. However the vertical ViewPager examples that I have found, seem to be problematic or depreciated. That is why I chose to pursue RecyclerView at a possible solution for my application build.

Comment: hardcoding the height is never advised in programming

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a more research,
 the best solution would be to use ViewPager.